How to fix error in get doc from Google API?
from google.oauth2.service_account import Credentials
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
import random
import msvcrt 
import json

credentials_doc = 'service_account.json'


service_account_info = json.load(open(credentials_doc))
credentials = Credentials.from_service_account_info(service_account_info)
service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)

document_id='my_doc_drive_id'

document = service.comments().get(documentId=document_id).execute()
print(document)

error:

document = service.comments().get(documentId=document_id).execute()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
raise TypeError("Got an unexpected keyword argument {}".format(name))
TypeError: Got an unexpected keyword argument documentId
how can i get my document
**
drivelink:https://docs.google.com/document/d/my_doc_drive_id**
I want to get my drive doc infos and processing incomings

From how can i get my document ** drivelink:https://docs.google.com/document/d/my_doc_drive_id** and I want to get my drive doc infos and processing incomings, I believe that your goal is as follows.

You want to retrieve a Google Document by googleapis for Python.
Your service account can access the Google Document of document_id='my_doc_drive_id'.

Modification points:

Your script tries to retrieve the comment from a file using Drive API. Also, when the comment is retrieved, it is required to use fileId and commentId. From your question, I guess that your document_id='my_doc_drive_id' might be the Google Document ID which is not a comment ID. I guessed that this might be the reason for your current issue.

If you want to retrieve the Google Document, it is required to use Google Docs API.
Modified script:
from google.oauth2.service_account import Credentials
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
import json

credentials_doc = 'service_account.json'

service_account_info = json.load(open(credentials_doc))
credentials = Credentials.from_service_account_info(service_account_info)

service = build('docs', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

document_id='my_doc_drive_id' # Please set your Google Document ID.

document = service.documents().get(documentId=document_id).execute()
print(document)


When this script is run, when your service account can access the Document of document_id='my_doc_drive_id', the object from Google Document is retrieved.

Note:

If you want to retrieve the file metadata of Google Documents using Drive API, I think that the following script can be used.
from google.oauth2.service_account import Credentials
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
import json

credentials_doc = 'service_account.json'

service_account_info = json.load(open(credentials_doc))
credentials = Credentials.from_service_account_info(service_account_info)

service = build("drive", "v3", credentials=credentials)

document_id='my_doc_drive_id' # Please set your Google Document ID.

document = service.files().get(fileId=document_id, fields="*").execute()
print(document)



References:

Method: comments.get of Drive API v3
Method: documents.get of Docs API v1
Method: files.get of Drive API v3



    document = service.files().get(fileId=document_id, fields="*").execute()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Resource' object has no attribute 'files' :(
problem solved with service = build('docs', 'v1', credentials=credentials) and document = service.documents().get(documentId=document_id).execute() thanks a lot

ok your answer helped me to solve it but the correct answer is in the comment and checked
